# How do I apply the conversion from charCodeAt to C # here?

Tags: javascript, c#

So I've already found posts on this topic, but that didn't really help me. On the one hand, I have tried something like this, for example, but it is not quite right in my case**(C#)**.

```
   string temp;

        foreach (var a in chaine)
           temp = ( Convert.ToUInt16(a).ToString("X4"));

        for (j = 0; j < intlenght; j+= 1)
        {
            arrayData[j + 1] = temp; 
}
```

Why I think it doesn't really work is that my starting form looked a little different than the examples and I'm not really familiar with JavaScript. My starting shape looks like this**(javaScript)**:

```
for (j = 0; j < intlenght; j+= 1)
        {
            arrayData[j + 1] = x.charCodeAt(j) - 32;
}
```

the **x** in this case it is actually

```
var x = document.getElementById ("textIn"). value;
```

but in my method I have a string return value instead of the **X**

so how can i correctly get the

> arrayData [j + 1] = x.charCodeAt (j) - 32;

translate in c #. In the end I need this in my method for Code128 encoder

**EDIT for better Understanding:**

So I have a TextBlock in my window, but there is a text in it in a barcode 128 font. However, this barcode cannot yet be read. So what I want to do is add the additional characters of the barcode so that at the end you can scan this barcode with a scanning program. To do that I come across this Stack Overflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60363928/17667316

However, the problem was with the question that the code is in JavaScript and not in C #. Since I've only found solutions where it works with libaries and nuggets (which I want to work around) I tried to convert this javaScript code into C #. I come across lines like this(**javaScript**):

```
arrayData[j + 1] = x.charCodeAt(j) - 32;
```

I didn't find a solution to this as I did this Javascript code:

```
    var buttonGen = document.getElementById("btnGen");
buttonGen.onclick = function () {
  var x = document.getElementById("textIn").value;
  var i, j, intWeight, intLength, intWtProd = 0, arrayData = [], fs;
  var arraySubst = [ "Ã", "Ä", "Å", "Æ", "Ç", "È", "É", "Ê" ];

/*
 * Checksum Calculation for Code 128 B
 */
  intLength = x.length;
    arrayData[0] = 104; // Assume Code 128B, Will revise to support A, C and switching.
    intWtProd = 104;
    for (j = 0; j < intLength; j += 1) {
            arrayData[j + 1] = x.charCodeAt(j) - 32; // Have to convert to Code 128 encoding
            intWeight = j + 1; // to generate the checksum
            intWtProd += intWeight * arrayData[j + 1]; // Just a weighted sum
    }
    arrayData[j + 1] = intWtProd % 103; // Modulo 103 on weighted sum
    arrayData[j + 2] = 106; // Code 128 Stop character
  chr = parseInt(arrayData[j + 1], 10); // Gotta convert from character to a number
  if (chr > 94) {
    chrString = arraySubst[chr - 95];
  } else {
    chrString = String.fromCharCode(chr + 32);
  }
  
  // Change the font-size style to match the drop down
  fs = document.getElementsByTagName("option")[document.getElementById("selList").selectedIndex].value;
  document.getElementById("test").style.fontSize = fs  + 'px';
  
  document.getElementById("check").innerHTML =
    'Checksum = ' + chr + ' or character ' + // Make It Visual
    chrString + ', for text = "' + x + '"';
  
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML =
    'Ì' + // Start Code B
    x + // The originally typed string
    chrString + // The generated checksum
    'Î'; // Stop Code
}
```

Can convert into a working C # code.

Comment: Could you please indent your code, state what are the languages for each excerpt of the codes you provided (the code is in javascript or C#?). And most importantly state what you want to achieve, in very simple terms

Comment: If your question is what I think it is "how do I get the integer representation of any character at position j within a string" then: strings are implemented as intrinsic char arrays in c#, to get a character at particular position you would simply use `yourstring[j]`, and chars are integers with a width of two bytes in c#, the integer value for them is themselves but you can cast them such as `(int)yourChar`. [Make sure to check out the MSDN on it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#accessing-individual-characters)

Comment: I edited my Question, may that will help better to understand my Problem